# CSS imgBox Links not working

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, href

I'm trying to code a Nav bar for my site but as soon as I implemented css imgBox my links stopped working. The're in the same directory so I don't believe this is the problem but for the life of me I can't figure out what's wrong
here's the HTML code

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li> <div class="imgBox"  id="img1"> <a href="index.html"> </a> </div> </li>
    <li> <div class="imgBox"  id="img2"> <a href="Media.html"> </a> </div> </li>  
    <li> <div class="imgBox"  id="img3"> <a href="social-media.html"> </a> </div> </li>
</ul>
```

and here's the css

```
.imgBox
{
    float:left;
    border: 1px solid #9325BC;
}
#img1
{
    background: url(images/home.png) no-repeat;
    width: 129px;
    height: 50px;
}

#img2
{
    background: url(images/media.png) no-repeat;
    width: 112px;
    height: 50px;
}

.imgBox:hover
{
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 30px #0000cc;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 30px #0000cc;
    box-shadow: 0 0 30px #0000cc;
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: you didnt close your `<a>` tags with `</a>` and you also have missing `</div>` tags...or are those typos?

Comment: Your anchor tags are empty and the first 2 don't have closing tags.

Comment: just added them but aptana sometimes flags them and asks me to remove them. Editing post now though, unfortunately doesn't resolve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<ul id="menu">
<li><a href="index.html"> <div class="imgBox"  id="img1">  </div></a> </li>
<li><a href="Media.html"> <div class="imgBox"  id="img2"></a>  </li>  
<li><a href="social-media.html">  <div class="imgBox"  id="img3"> </a></li>
</ul>
```

Is this what you're trying to do?

Comment: Thanks jfoutch enclosing the <div> element within the <a> element seems to solve the problem! Cannot tell you how long I've been sitting with this problem. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

You must close all tags you open. link tags and div tags. Also if you want your link to be visible it must contain at least a word or image.

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li><div class="imgBox"  id="img1"> <a href="index.html">Index</a> </div> </li>
    <li> <div class="imgBox"  id="img2"> <a href="Media.html">Media</a> </div></li>  
    <li> <div class="imgBox"  id="img3"> <a href="social-media.html"> Social media</a></div></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Working version of your question can be found here: [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/oyeepqq3/4/)

```
<li> <div class="imgBox"  id="img1"> <a href="index.html"> Some Text here</a> </div> </li>
```

The problem was that you did not close your href element